# How can I control the colors used of the popover controls appearing with the options to "Copy" / "Cut", "Paste"?

Tags: flutter

After a long press on an editable textfield, both in android and iOS, the expected control appear with the options to "Copy", "Paste" etc. For some reason, on both platforms, this control appears for me as dark text on a dark background.

I tried searching the docs for how can I control this in the Theme/Colors files, and couldn't find any mention of this control anywhere.
[Screenshot of the dark text on dark background in the control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qg80n.png)

The [documentation of the TextField widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField-class.html) has no mention of the copy/paste control and of the possible configurations of it.

How can I control the appearance of this control in flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Flutter bug that has been recently fixed: [TextField editing menu text color reflects PrimarySwatch theme on iOS #26914](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26914).

Here's a quote from the bug report:

> The editing menu on iOS when using a `TextField` widget now reflects the `PrimarySwatch` color theme which is unexpected. Type some text into a `TextField` and select it and observe the text color of the menu options. Building against the `stable` channel looks fine, but building against `master` shows the issue. This becomes noticeable when your `PrimarySwatch` happens to be grey or another darker color. Android looks ok, only iOS seems to be a problem.

The bug was fixed on Feb. 7, 2019, however the last release of Flutter, v. 1.2.0, was in January 2019. There's a good chance the fix will be in the next release of Flutter.